# Can I show a modern calendar inside a SharePoint modern page which dynamically shows the login user Outlook calendar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, outlook, events

Inside SharePoint Online >> we can add the "Events" modern web part, as follow:-

[image]

Which will show this calendar layout:

[image]

Now we want to have the same layout for a personalized calendar which dynamically show the login users' events from their outlook calendar.. so how we can achieve this?
The only way I find, is that we can use Power Apps as mentioned in this link @ https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Can-we-build-a-Power-Apps-to-show-the-login-user-personal/td-p/1588336, but the issue is that the calendar layout will be different from the SharePoint built-in calendar view, something as follow:-

[image]

any advice?